# I have an AWS Elasticsearch instance that I want to change the delimiter used when tokenizing

Tags: elasticsearch, delimiter, tokenize, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-jest

I'm currently using Jest to communicate with an AWS Elasticsearch instance running Elasticsearch 5.3. One of the fields is a URL, but I don't think a single period without following white space is considered a delimiter by default when Elasticsearch tokenizes. Therefore, I can't search for "www.google.com" with "google," for example.

I'd really like to be able to add a single period to the delimiter pattern. I've seen documentation on Elasticsearch's website about how to alter the delimiter when using Elasticsearch natively, but I haven't seen anyone change it through Jest. Is this possible, and if so, how would I go about doing so?

I'd like to configure it using some client in a Java application if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that a pattern Tokenizer could help. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-analyzer.html

Or a char filter where you could replace a dot by a space? See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-mapping-charfilter.html

Comment: I saw the pattern analyzer and it seemed like a solid option; my question was more related to how I should make the request (through Jest or some other client). I should've also mentioned that I'd like to make it through a Java application, I've edited it to include that. Sorry if my question was worded poorly